# Custom Settings in Managed Package limits

Tags: managed-package, governorlimits, customsetting, data

So I have a use case where I will have many custom settings and each custom setting has many fields so easily getting in several MB of custom settings data.

If I put this into a managed package where all the custom settings will be public how does this effect the following -

a) The total amount of cached data allowed for your organization is the lesser of these two values:

- 10 MB
- 1 MB multiplied by the number of full-featured user licenses in your organization

b) Custom settings are a type of custom object. Each custom setting counts against the total number of custom objects available for your organisation.

For b) my guess would be there is no impact on custom object count as its a managed package.

For a) I'm not so sure, is 10MB a hard limit for the org and is set 'high' as it is expected this limit will not be hit across all managed packages and customers customer settings combined.

What happens if there is 3MB of custom settings data and only 1 user in the org (so only 1MB of custom settings data is allowed)?

Does public custom settings size within a managed package count towards the custom settings size limits within the org?

Comment: Wow, yet another inexplicably conservative limit that I wasn't aware of. Based on the docs, though, you'd be out of luck - that 1-user org only can store 1MB of custom settings. I'd be very surprised if managed packages get an exemption, since this is a data storage limit. If you find out a definitive answer, please post it here. Agree on b, you will have no impact on custom object count if you've passed security review.

Comment: Please look at the below link. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34230/custom-settings-limit-cached-data-limit

Answer (score 2):

I've had some experience with this area and asked similar questions to Salesforce.

***"For b) my guess would be there is no impact on custom object count as its a managed package."***

Yes providing your package has Aloha status (which requires Security Review to be passed).

***"For a) I'm not so sure, is 10MB a hard limit for the org and is set 'high' as it is expected this limit will not be hit across all managed packages and customers customer settings combined."***

Public and Private custom settings also share this regardless. My notes from the last time I discussed this with Salesforce indicate this is scoped by namespace/package. Though I note the documentation does not reflect this, I would raise a support case to confirm this.

***"What happens if there is 3MB of custom settings data and only 1 user in the org (so only 1MB of custom settings data is allowed)?"***

When you reach the limit you will receive a run time exception from Apex code and a mesage in the UI if creating manually. According to my reading of the docs one (licensed) user will only result in 1MB of maximum cache for settings. Hence the '**lesser**' highlighted in bold in the docs.

> The total amount of cached data allowed for your organization is the lesser of these two values:
>   10 MB
>   1 MB multiplied by the number of full-featured user licenses in your organization
>   For example, if your organization has three full licenses, you have 3 MB of custom setting storage. If your organization has six full licenses, you have 10 MB of storage.

[Custom Setting Limits](http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/cs_limits.htm).

Comment: Not *quite* scoped by namespace/package--non-Aloha packages count towards the organization's regular pool. But each Aloha package gets its own pool. And actually, as of Summer 15, this *is* documented -- https://goo.gl/gl2vKA , in particular the section starting "Each certified managed package..."

Answer (score 1):

Andy is right about your a) question--custom settings in Aloha packages don't count against your organizations object limit (except the hard limit of 2000 objects per org).

Each certified managed package gets its own "pool" for its own custom settings data. This pool, however, is equal to the size of the pool for the *installing* organization.

So say you have some custom settings (protected or public doesn't matter) in an Aloha-certified managed package, and you install it into two orgs:

1. An org with 1 user and 900K of custom settings data already
2. An org with 10 users and 9MB of custom settings data already

Your custom settings will be able to hold up to 1MB in the first org, and 10MB in the second org--so org size matters, but not how much custom settings data they already have.